# R: power.t.test: How to estimate required sampling size for UNKNOWN population variance?

Tags: r, variance

I am trying to use the following code in R to estimate the required sampling size to reach certain power and significant level for UNKNOWN population variance:

```
power.t.test(delta = 5, sd=sigma, sig.level=0.05, power = .80, type="one.sample", alternative = "one.sided")
```

In the code above, `sigma` is a predefined value. Because the population variance is UNKNOWN, I think I need to use `sd = NULL` instead of `sd=sigma`. However, when it is `sd = NULL`, I got the error message:

```
Error in power.t.test(delta = 5, sd = NULL, sig.level = 0.05, power = 0.8,  
:exactly one of 'n', 'delta', 'sd', 'power', and 'sig.level' must be NULL
```

So can I ask how to properly set the arguments?

Comment: Welcome to CV. Please note that this site is not intended to be a resource for software-specific questions. You may want to rephrase your question in more general terms.

Comment: Do you have any possible guesses as to the population variance? It is typically in power analyses to try a range of values to have best case/worst case scenarios.

Comment: The error message tells you exactly how to specify the arguments.

Comment: @ssdecontrol
I think I understood "known variance" and "unknown variance" incorrectly. Now I think ONLY one of 'n', 'delta', 'sd', 'power', and 'sig.level' can be unknown while the others should be known.

Comment: @lanselibai that's correct. Instead of "must be NULL" maybe the error should say "must be set to NULL" or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

Adjusted my answer:

If you specify n and set sd to NULL you get the answer. I made a loop to show a range of sd's.

```
n <- c(100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000)

for(i in 1:length(n)){
  t <- power.t.test(n = n[i], sd = NULL, delta = 5, sig.level=0.05, power = .80, type="one.sample", alternative = "one.sided")
  print(t$sd)
}

[1] 19.97089
[1] 63.54651
[1] 201.0743
[1] 635.8914
[1] 2010.878
```

Comment: No, if 'sd' is not defined, it will use its default value, which is 'sd=1'.

The Usage for the 'power.t.test' is:

power.t.test(n = NULL, delta = NULL, sd = 1, sig.level = 0.05, power = NULL, type = c("two.sample", "one.sample", "paired"), alternative = c("two.sided", "one.sided"), strict = FALSE, tol = .Machine$double.eps^0.25)

Comment: thank you. Now I understand that ONLY one of 'n', 'delta', 'sd', 'power', and 'sig.level' can be unknown while the others should be known.